# eclipse error: glassfish\domains\domain1 does not exist

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3

I have java ee6 web profile sdk & I am using eclipse ee. I installed Glassfish plugin for eclipse using *Download additional server adapters* in the *New Server* wizard. Now during building a test app, eclipse raise this error  **glassfish\domains\domain1 does not exist**. Whats the reason & how can I remove it?

Comment: Do you have a domain1 directory in your glassfish/domains folder?

Answer (score 9):

Either your eclipse glassfish plugin points to the wrong domain or your server has no domain although there should be at least a default domain which is usually named *domain1*.

Check what's the name of your domain in *glassfish-install-dir\glassfish\domains* directory. If there is no subdir, you can create a domain with the asadmin tool:

```
glassfish-install-dir\bin\asadmin create-domain your-domain-name
```

See [this description of the create-domain command](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19798-01/821-1758/create-domain-1/index.html).

If you already have a domain with a different name than *domain1*, you have to reconfigure your eclipse glassfish plugin. (Since I don't use eclipse, I can't take you any further. But I remember a [BalusC tutorial on this topic](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html)).

Comment: I do not create any domain. Just installed Java EE 6 web profile. Then installed glassfish plugin & now encounter this problem. I tried to run the command glassfish\bin\asadmin create-domain doamin1, but cmd gives error,'system cannot find path specified.'

Comment: @user701854 : updated my answer and clarified directories. Note that there is a glassfish dir inside your glassfish-install-dir. And there should be your domains.

Comment: yes & I used path pf same. It precisely is 'D:\Java6EE\glassfish\bin\asadmin'. I used this path but strangely cmd gives path error. I followed all steps given in BalusC tutorial except just not creating any admin acc when installing Java EE web profile & leaving both fields admin/pass blank.

Comment: What is inside your glassfish\domains directory?

Answer (score 7):

Go to `<Glassfish-install-directory>/glassfish/config` directory.

Edit `asenv` and point to your JDK installation for `set AS_JAVA=C:\Java\jdk`.

Now you should be able to run `asadmin`.

Create a new domain using `asadmin create-domain domain1` (inside bin directory).

Server setup in eclipse will now find your newly created domain.

Comment: doesn't work..still saying domain cannot be created.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem and fixed it with the following:

1. Open a command prompt and browse to `C:\glassfish3\glassfish\bin` (or whatever your glassfish directory is)
2. Execute `asadmin`
3. Type in [create-domain](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1751/ggnop/index.html) `--adminport 4848 domain1` (your debug port can probably be whatever)
4. Go back into Eclipse and continue

Answer (score 1):

Although late reply, but may be useful to someone facing similar issues.

If no domain exists in your glassfish path i.e say `C:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\` then you can create a new domain in the same path as follows:

1. Navigate to `C:\glassfish4\bin\` directory and double click on `asadmin.bat`. It will open a command prompt as `asadmin >`
2. Type the following command `asadmin > create-domain --adminport 4848 domain1`
3. Click <kbd>Enter</kbd> repeatedly to keep the default settings viz. username (admin) password and other things.

That's it. You will find the `domain1` created under `C:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\` directory with all default configurations.

If want to create domain in another directory or want some more info then can refer Oracle Glassfish Reference Manual:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1758/create-domain-1/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse doesn't have domain path setting for glassfish server. This error comes when domain path is not correct. Make sure when you run your application on eclipse give glassfish credentials user/password

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the C:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\ **domain.xml** was renamed to something like domain**568912323464576456**.xml, so I edited the file, leaving it as it supposed to be named and done, server started up again.

Answer (score 0):

create a new domain with

```
asadmin create-domain myDomain
```

add the path of this new domain, if there is a message "domain is not valid", make the folder domains/myDomain/conf permission to not only the root. If there is the message "is not writtable" then open Eclipse as root and try again. This should be work in these cases.

Answer (score -1):

You must to add a password to your admin user. Eclipse mistake. Eclipse doesn't recognise the domain without admin password.

When you create the domain, add a admin user and a password and Eclipse doesn't complain any more.