# Installing Glassfish Server with installer fails on Windows 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-4

iam a complete newbie in this area and dont know what to do.

For a Java ee tutorial i have to install the GlassFish server on my Windows 7.

I have followed the instructions and installed the newest JDK.

After i have downloaded the GlassFish native installer with multilingual from this website
[glassfish.java.net/download.html](https://glassfish.java.net/download.html) i pressed the exe and it starts to install, but after 30
seconds it stops and a window pops and says that the software was not correctly installed that i 
have to do it again with the correct settings. The result of the tried install is that the GlassFish 
installer creates a glassfish4 folder under c:/glassfish4 but the glassfish4 folder is complete empty.
The newest JDK is installed even so i did not know what to do. Than i choose to install the GlassFish 
server 3 and everything worked fine. A glassfish3 folder was created under c:/glassfish3 and i have 
installed the glassfish tools for eclipse. The problem here is that the glassfish3 installer did not create the domain1 folder. I followed the instruction given in this question

[eclipse error: glassfish\domains\domain1 does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635483/eclipse-error-glassfish-domains-domain1-does-not-exist)

but the command

> glassfish-install-dir\bin\asadmin create-domain your-domain-name

doesnt work i get the same error message like the poster of this question that cmd gives path error.

I also tried to execute the glassFish4 installer exe as admin but it failed also.

Now i dont know what to and how to install the GlassFish4 server correctly it is so frustrating.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command:

```
glassfish-install-dir\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat create-domain --adminport 4848 domain1
```

And then try to start it again.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem few days back. Please follow the instruction.
Glass Fish Server may be searching for proper JDK before creating a domain.
You can download zip archive for glass fish server and unzip it and use it as server.
This zip file already will have default domain created.

If you want to install it. Then please follow the below mention steps.

Step 1.
Go to /glassfish/config

Step 2.

Open asenv.bat in editor and edit set AS_JAVA=""
Mention jre installation path properly. It should be till bin directory.
Step 3.

Save file and start glassfish server installation again.

Step 4.

Choose "Custom Installation" press next

Step 5.

Choose "Configure an existing installation"

Step 6.

Mention the older installation directory and follow the instructions.

Domain1 should be created.

Comment: If this does not help, please inform.